# Using nested objects within query hits multiple indices in Nest ElasticSearch

Tags: nest

I have two types **producttype** and **accounttype** inside **product** and **account** indices, and I need to construct a search query to hit both of them.

Right now I have ended up with the following query:

```
var searchResponse = elasticClient.Search<object>(s => s
            .Index(indices)
            .Type(Types.Type(typeof(ProductType), typeof(accountType)))
            .Query(q => q
                 q.Nested(n => n
                   .Path(Infer.Field<ProductType>(ff => ff.Keywords))
                   .Query(nq => nq
                       .Match(t => t
                         .Field(Infer.Field<ProductType>(ff => ff.Keywords.First().Keyword))
                         .Query(query)
                       )
                       ||
                       nq.Term(Infer.Field<ProductType>(ff => ff.Keywords.First().Keyword.Suffix("keyword")), query)
                   )
                 )
                && 
                +q.Term("_type", "producttype") 
                || 
                q.MultiMatch(m => m
                    .Fields(f => f
                        .Field(Infer.Field<accountType>(ff => ff.AccountName, 1.5))
                        .Field(Infer.Field<accountType>(ff => ff.Description, 0.8))
                    )
                    .Operator(Operator.Or)
                    .Query(query)
                ) && 
                +q.Term("_type", "accounttype")
            )
        );
```

When I run this query it doesn't work because of keywords nested object not found inside accounttype(but in my case I am filtering by _type so it should work).

So how can I filter by _index/_type when I have nested object inside one index?

Answer (score 0):

Try by adding .IgnoreUnmapped(true) inside Nested object.

```
var searchResponse = elasticClient.Search<object>(s => s
            .Index(indices)
            .Type(Types.Type(typeof(ProductType), typeof(accountType)))
            .Query(q => q
                 q.Nested(n => n
                   .IgnoreUnmapped(true)
                   .Path(Infer.Field<ProductType>(ff => ff.Keywords))
                   .Query(nq => nq
                       .Match(t => t
                         .Field(Infer.Field<ProductType>(ff => ff.Keywords.First().Keyword))
                         .Query(query)
                       )
                       ||
                       nq.Term(Infer.Field<ProductType>(ff => ff.Keywords.First().Keyword.Suffix("keyword")), query)
                   )
                 )
                && 
                +q.Term("_type", "producttype") 
                || 
                q.MultiMatch(m => m
                    .Fields(f => f
                        .Field(Infer.Field<accountType>(ff => ff.AccountName, 1.5))
                        .Field(Infer.Field<accountType>(ff => ff.Description, 0.8))
                    )
                    .Operator(Operator.Or)
                    .Query(query)
                ) && 
                +q.Term("_type", "accounttype")
            )
        );
```